# Hovering a split rectangle div

Tags: html, css

Think about a rectangular div, which is split into 2 parts, each part is L shaped (like shown below), region 1 for left-side L and region 2 for right-side L.

I would like to hover, change the background color for example, region 1 on mouse-over, same for region 2. Is there any way to do it with CSS (without using javascript) ?

```
 ____ ___
|  __|  |
|_|_____|
```

Comment: Got some html/css you can share? Sounds like all you need is `:hover` in CSS

Comment: I'm more curious about how you get that division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nts32/***

**html**

```
<div id="left">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="right">   
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#left, #right {
    height:300px;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
}

#left > div, #right >div {
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute; 
}

#left, #left > div {    
    background-color:#cef;  
}

#right, #right > div {  
    background-color:#fec;
    left:300px;  
}

#left > div {
    left:150px;   
}

#right > div {
    left:-150px;
    top:150px;  
}

#left:hover, #left:hover > div {
    background-color:#acd;   
}

#right:hover, #right:hover > div {
    background-color:#dca;   
}
```

Comment: Works on ie7 (tested on ie9 on ie7 mode). Did bother checking anything below.

Answer (score 1):

That was fun..

http://jsfiddle.net/aaVKZ/1/

Trick is that each half of the rectangle is actually made up of two `div`s.  Then each pair of `div`s is contained within a common parent.  That parent has the `:hover` applied.